# GCP Cloud Logging Cost increasing with Dataproc img version 2.0.39-ubuntu18

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataproc, google-cloud-logging

I've a Dataproc cluster with image version - 2.0.39-ubuntu18, which seems to be putting all logs into Cloud Logging, this is increasing our costs a lot.

Here is the command used to create the cluster, i've added the following - spark:spark.eventLog.dir=gs://dataproc-spark-logs/joblogs,spark:spark.history.fs.logDirectory=gs://dataproc-spark-logs/joblogs

to stop using the Cloud Logging, however that is not working .. Logs are being re-directed to Cloud Logging as well.

Here is the command used to create the Dataproc cluster :

```
REGION=us-east1
ZONE=us-east1-b
IMG_VERSION=2.0-ubuntu18
NUM_WORKER=3

# in versa-sml-googl
gcloud beta dataproc clusters create $CNAME \
           --enable-component-gateway \
           --bucket $BUCKET \
           --region $REGION \
           --zone $ZONE \
           --no-address --master-machine-type $TYPE \
           --master-boot-disk-size 100 \
           --master-boot-disk-type pd-ssd \
           --num-workers $NUM_WORKER \
           --worker-machine-type $TYPE \
           --worker-boot-disk-type pd-ssd \
           --worker-boot-disk-size 500 \
           --image-version $IMG_VERSION \
           --autoscaling-policy versa-dataproc-autoscaling \
           --scopes 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform' \
           --project $PROJECT \
           --initialization-actions 'gs://dataproc-spark-configs/pip_install.sh','gs://dataproc-spark-configs/connectors-feb1.sh' \
           --metadata 'gcs-connector-version=2.0.0' \
           --metadata 'bigquery-connector-version=1.2.0' \
           --properties 'dataproc:dataproc.logging.stackdriver.job.driver.enable=true,dataproc:job.history.to-gcs.enabled=true,spark:spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled=false,spark:spark.executor.instances=6,spark:spark.executor.cores=2,spark:spark.eventLog.dir=gs://dataproc-spark-logs/joblogs,spark:spark.history.fs.logDirectory=gs://dataproc-spark-logs/joblogs,spark:spark.jars.packages=org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12:3.1.2'
```

We have another Dataproc cluster (image version 1.4.37-ubuntu18, similar configuration as the image version 2.0-ubuntu18), which has similar configuration but does not seem to using Cloud Logging as much.

Attached is screenshot properties of both the clusters.

What do i need to change to ensure the Dataproc jobs(pyspark) donot use the Cloud Logging ?

tia!

[image: image-v1.x-1]
[image: image-v1.x-2]
[image: image-v1.x-3]
[[image: image-v2.x-1][4]]
[image: image-v2.x-2]
[image: image-v2.x-3]

Comment: As a workaround, you can use an init action which runs `systemctl stop google-fluentd.service` to disable Cloud Logging.

Comment: @Dagang - i was trying disable logging using the following command  -> gcloud beta resource-manager org-policies enable-enforce \
  constraints/gcp.disableCloudLogging --project x4-stag .. or do i need to logon the fluentd VM to stop the Cloud Logging ?

Comment: That disables Cloud Logging on the service side, which is sufficient. Stopping `google-fluentd` on nodes stops logs from the client side.

Comment: @Dagang - thanks, i'll check this .. qq - is the logging (volume, type etc) changed in the later versions of Dataproc ? i don't see this behavior in the earlier 1.x images

Comment: I am not aware of any major changes, but if you can find which logs are increased, I can help investigate.

Comment: You can also change the properties upon the creation of the said cluster and disable the logging from there using the following command.: `--properties 'dataproc:dataproc.logging.stackdriver.job.driver.enable=failse`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the update on this (based on discussions with GCP Support) :

In the GCP Logging, we need to create a Log Routing sink with inclusion filter - this will write the logs to BigQuery or Cloud Storage depending upon the target you specify.

Additionally, the _Default sink needs to be modified to add exclusion filters so specific logs will NOT be re-directed to GCP Logging

Attached are screenshots of the _Default log sink and the Inclusion sink for Dataproc.

[image: Inclusion Sink]

[image: _Default sink with Exclusion filters added]

Answer (score 0):

I saw `dataproc:dataproc.logging.stackdriver.job.driver.enable` is set to `true`. By default, the value is `false`, which means driver logs will be saved to GCS and streamed back to the client for viewing, but it won't be saved to Cloud Logging. You can try disabling it. BTW, when it is enabled, the job driver logs will be available in Cloud Logging under the job resource (instead of the cluster resource).

If you want to disable Cloud Logging completely for a cluster, you can either add `dataproc:dataproc.logging.stackdriver.enable=false` when creating the cluster or write an init action with `systemctl stop google-fluentd.service`. Both will stop Cloud Logging on the cluster's side, but using property is recommended.

See [Dataproc cluster properties](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/configuring-clusters/cluster-properties) for the property.